# Ajax funciona local, mas não funciona no servidor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, visual-studio-2012

tenho uma aplicação em asp.net mvc 5 em que o código abaixo funciona localmente (visual studio 2012), mas não funciona após a publicação no servidor.

```
controllerAction = "/Controller/Action/"
controller = "/Controller/"

$('#approve-btn').click(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: controllerAction,
    data: { id: idElementoClicado },
    datatype: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#ajaxgrid").load(controller + ' #ajaxgrid', function () {
        });

    },
    error: function () {
        alert(response);
    }
});

$('#modal-container').modal('hide');
});

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Excluir(CentroCustoViewModel viewModel)
{
  //bloco de execução

  return Json(datasource, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Ao clicar no botão que dispara a ação sempre cai no evento de error e emite o alert.

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Obrigado

Answer (score 3):

No seu `<body>` da **MasterPage** coloque assim:

`<body data-base="http://www.dominio.com.br/">`

Em `data-base` seria seu LINK principal.

Depois crie uma variável global (ou não) no JS:

`var baseURL;`

E depois:

`baseURL = $('body').data('base');`

Depois aqui nas variáveis de caminho coloque ela:

```
controllerAction = baseURL + "/Controller/Action"
controller = baseURL + "/Controller"
```

Outra coisa, tira a `/` do final da URL quando por **POST**.

Comment: Funcionou não Zoom. :(

Comment: Como deve ser seu LINK no Localhost quando chama essa função e qual é o domínio que está usando na hospedagem ? Editei meu post com uma alteração.

Comment: Tirei a '/' do final e continuou a mesma coisa (funcionou localmente e não funcionou no servidor).
O link é montado corretamente http://servidor/nomedaaplicacao/controller/action/Id

Comment: Veja o erro que dá no Inspect Element do Chrome.

Comment: Esse é o problema, não da erro. A ação não acontece.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução paliativa para está situação seria nomear uma variável/constante com o seu domínio.

Por exemplo:

```
var siteRoot = 'www.meusite.com.br/';
```

a paliatividade está justamente no conteúdo desta variável, pois desta forma funcionará apenas no servidor/hospedagem. Quando pretender utilizar local, deverá inserir o prefixo do servidor local.
por exemplo:

```
var siteRoot = 'localhost/meuprojeto/';
```

Outra forma (não muito organizada) é descrever o caminho a partir do arquivo.

Para compreender o exemplo, vamos simular uma estrutura de pastas do projeto:

```
/raiz
--/imagens
----------/logo
---------------/logo_principal.png
----------/imagem00.png
----------/imagem01.png
----------/imagem02.png
--/codigos_css
----------/style.css
--/codigos_javascript
----------/functions_ajax.js
--/classes
----------/bd.class.php
----------/crud.class.php
--/log
----------/log.txt
--/index.asp
--/produtos.asp
```

Supondo agora que o local que você chame a função do Jquery que conectará via Ajax seja o '**functions_ajax.js**' e sua intenção é acessar o conteúdo do arquivo PHP '**bd.class.php**', encontrado dentro da pasta '**classes**'.

O caminha para acessar o arquivo desejado, obedecendo a estrutura de pastas, seria:

```
../classes/bd.class.php
```

logo

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:'../classes/bd.class.php',
  data: { id: idElementoClicado },
  datatype: "html",
  success: function (data) {
    $("#ajaxgrid").load(controller + ' #ajaxgrid', function () {
    });

  },
  error: function (jqXHR,msgError) {
    alert(msgError);
  }
});
```

Comment: thelimarenan, o caminho está correto o problema é que não ocorre uma ação entre o front-end e o back-end.

Comment: Reparei uma coisa, mas não sei se servira para algo:

Dê uma olhada na condição de Error do Jquery.
Por padrão ela retorna três parâmetros:

" jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus e String errorThrown "

Tenta colocar ao menos dois deles para Testar

Obs: assim como na minha resposta [editada]

Comment: Bom dia thelimarenan, descobri o erro mas ainda não sei como resolve-lo.

A aplicação é chamada pela url: http://servidor e obviamente a aplicação é chamada pela url: http://servidor/aplicacao. A aplicação não funcionava, foi quando eu pesquisando vi que deveria colocar a seguinte tag no web.config:

<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

Alterei o erro do Ajax para:

 error: function (response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    }

Pelo jeito o Ajax está com problemas de rota.

Comment: Só não esqueça que o primeiro parâmetro retorna o código do erro, insira um segundo parâmetro para ver a String do Erro.ex: error: function (response,errortext) { alert(JSON.stringify(errortext)); }

Comment: O response retorna um html (foi lah que vi que ha muitas referêcias do web site). O errortext me retorna apenas uma string 'error'. Ha alguma coisa a mais para alterar?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver!!!
O problema é que o

```
System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid
```

estava matando o ajax, por isso se perdia no caminho.

Alterei a url do ajax para:

```
'@Url.Action("NomeDaAction","NomeDoController")'
```

e retirei a seguinte linha antes do @grid.GetHtml(...)

```
 using ((Html.BeginForm()))
 {
```